# MongoDB query (range filter + sort) performance tuning

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a Mongo collection containing millions of documents with the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac37fa989e00723fc4c7746"),
    "group-number" : NumberLong(128125089),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-03T13:20:41.193Z")
}
```

And I want to retrieve the documents between 2 dates ('*date*') sorted by '*group-numbe*r'. So, I am executing this kind of queries:

```
db.getCollection('group').find({date:{$gt:new Date(1491372960000),$lt:new Date(1553152560000)}}).sort({"group-number":1})
```

According to https://blog.mlab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/ it seems that MongoDB when not querying by **equivalent** values but with **range** values (as in my case), it is better to have an index in the inverse order (first the sorted field / then the filtered field).
Indeed, I've had the best results with the index `db.group.createIndex({"group-number":1,"date":1});`. But still it takes too long; in same cases more than 40 seconds.

According to the *explain()* results, indeed the above index is being used.

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : ISODate("2019-03-21T07:16:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-04-05T06:16:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "group-number" : 1.0,
                    "date" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "group-number_1_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "group-number" : [],
                    "date" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "group-number" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "date" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I improve the performance? I must be missing something...

Comment: hey! did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, I finally gave up. Now I extract the data sorted by 'date' so I also had to adapt the process which deals with the data.

Comment: did you think about ETL to some columnar storage instead of querying mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

I'd build an index in a reverse way: `db.createIndex({date: 1, 'group-number': 1})`. Simply because you are actually querying via `date` field, so it should come first in the compound index. You are only using `group-number` for sorting. In such way it makes it easier for WiredTiger to find necessary documents in the BTree.

Comment: The reverse index is the one I had originally that performed even worse. Moreover, when both indexes are available ({"group-number":1,"date":1} & {"date":1,"group-number":1}) MongoDB still chooses the "group-number_1_date_1" index as shown in the explain() result above.

Comment: @Kuikiker interesting. What's the distribution of the field `group-number`? How many unique values does it have?

Comment: I cannot get the exact figures, but there are more than 100 million different 'group-number' starting from 1 to 158000000 (there are some gaps in between). But in the collection I am querying 'group-number' is not unique and can have multiple entries for each 'group-number'

Comment: Taken from: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ this seems to be my problem. "An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the index key pattern. To do so, the query must include equality conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys. If the query does not specify an equality condition on an index prefix that precedes or overlaps with the sort specification, the operation will not efficiently use the index"

Answer (score 0):

> According to the explain() results, indeed the above index is being used.

There is an important distinction between an index being used and an index being used *efficiently*. Taking a look at the index usage portion of the `explain` output, we have the following:

```
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "group-number" : 1.0,
                    "date" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "group-number_1_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "group-number" : [],
                    "date" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "group-number" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "date" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

There are two (related) important observations here:

- The index scan has not been bounded at all. The bounds for all (both) keys are `[MinKey, MaxKey]`. This means that the operation is scanning the *entire* index.
- The restrictions on the `date` field expressed by the query predicate are not present in either the index bounds (noted above) *or* even as a separate `filter` during the index scanning phase.

What we see instead is that the `date` bounds are only being applied *after* the full document has been retrieved:

```
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : ISODate("2019-03-21T07:16:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-04-05T06:16:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Taken together, this means that the operation that originally generated the explain output:

- Scanned the entire index
- Individually retrieved the full document associated with each key
- Filtered out the documents that did not match the `date` predicate
- Returned the remaining documents to the client

The *only* benefit that the index provided was the fact that it provided the results in sorted order. This may or may not be faster than just doing a full collection scan instead. That would depend on things like the number of matching results as well as the total number of documents in the collection.

##### Bounding `date`

An important question to ask would be why the database was not using the `date` field from the index more effectively?

As far as I can tell, this is (still) a quirk of how MongoDB creates index bounds. For whatever reason, it does not seem to recognize that the second index key can have bounds applied to it despite the fact that the first one does not.

We can, however, trick it into doing so. In particular we can apply a predicate against the sort field (`group-number`) that doesn't change the results. An example (using the newer `mongosh` shell) would be `"group-number" :{$gte: MinKey}`. This would make the full query:

```
db.getCollection('group').find({"group-number" :{$gte: MinKey}, date:{$gt:new Date(1491372960000),$lt:new Date(1553152560000)}}).sort({"group-number":1})
```

The `explain` for this adjusted query generates:

```
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: { 'group-number': 1, date: 1 },
        indexName: 'group-number_1_date_1',
        isMultiKey: false,
        multiKeyPaths: { 'group-number': [], date: [] },
        isUnique: false,
        isSparse: false,
        isPartial: false,
        indexVersion: 2,
        direction: 'forward',
        indexBounds: {
          'group-number': [ '[MinKey, MaxKey]' ],
          date: [ '(new Date(1491372960000), new Date(1553152560000))' ]
        }
      }
    }
```

We can see above that the `date` field is now bounded as expected preventing the database from having to unnecessarily retrieve documents that do not match the query predicate. This would likely provide some improvement to the query, but it is impossible to say how much without knowing more about the data distribution.

##### Other Observations

The index noted in the other answer swaps the order of the index keys. This may reduce the total number of index keys that need to be examined in order to execute the full query. However as noted in the comments, it prevents the database from using the index to provide sorted results. While there is always a tradeoff when it comes to queries that both use range operators and request a sort, my suspicion is that the index described in the question will be superior for this particular situation.

Was the sample document described in the question the full document? If so, then the database is only forced to retrieve the full document in order to gather the `_id` field to return to the client. You could transform this operation into a [covered query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) (one that can return results directly from the index alone without having to retrieve the full document) by either:

- Projecting out the `_id` field in the query if the client does not need it, or
- Appending `_id` to the index in the last position if the client does want it.